# Is this possible to translate part of the web page using Google Website Translator gadget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, translation, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I have a web page designed with asp.net.I am using **Google Website Translator gadget** for translating my entire webpage to different languages.But some of my pages are needs only the part of the web page to be translated.for example,in my web page i displayed a List box control.Now i want to translate the content of the List box only.

Is this possible with **Google Website Translator Gadget**?

Please guide me a way to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `class="notranslate"`.

It works for me:

```
<body>

<span class="notranslate">
content...
</span>


<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>


<span class="notranslate">
other content...
</span>

</body>
```

In this example, "`content...`" and "`other content...`" will not be translated and "`One`" and "`Two`" in select box will be translated.

Result:

```
<body>

<span class="notranslate">
content...
</span>


<select>
    <option value="1">یک</option>
    <option value="2">دو</option>
</select>


<span class="notranslate">
other content...
</span>

</body>
```